# unable to get the logs from ecs fargate container

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am trying to find the logs for one of my serivces in ECS. I have successfully assigned ssh policy to IAM role used in a task definition.
After running the task, I run below command to exec into my task container.

```
aws ecs execute-command --cluster test-cluster --task 1b6338********f04d50ae4362241 --container test-service --command "bash" --interactive
```

Challenge is that I am not able to see the logs under the logs folder.
[image]
What am I missing above ?

Comment: If you are running a container on Fargate, as your title says, then EC2 is not involved in running your container at all. Yet you have tagged your question with `amazon-ec2` and logged into an EC2 instance via SSH to look for the logs there for some reason. First I suggest figuring out if you are actually using Fargate or EC2. Second, I suggest looking at the log driver settings in the ECS task definition to see if you have the task configured to send the logs anywhere like CloudWatch Logs.

Comment: @MarkB thanks for pointing out incorrect tag. I am using fargate to run my containers. Now, when I have successfully SSH into fargate containers, I can't see my logs in the log folder.

Comment: What logs do you expect to see in that folder? Does the application you have running in the docker container actually write any logs to `/var/log`? Inside the container itself, you won't find any container logs, you will only find logs that specific processes inside the container have written to the container's disk volume. Again, please look at the ECS Task Definition's logdriver configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @mark from  the comments for clarifying.

After configuring the task definition with `CloudWatch` I have been able to log real time logs using aws cli.

`aws logs tail "/ecs/my-services" --follow --since 30m`